# Capacitor - Trying to catch the cancel on camera

Tags: ios-camera, ionic4, capacitor

I am using Capacitor with Ionic 4 and I would like to catch when the user taps on cancel when on the camera.

```
public async takePicture(): Promise<string> {

    const image: CameraPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 90,
        allowEditing: true,
        correctOrientation: true,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
        source: CameraSource.Camera
    }).catch((e) => {
        throw new Error(e);
    });

    return this._IMAGE = image.webPath;
}
```

I am simply try to catch and error but clicking on cancel does not throw an error anymore when compared to cordova. How do I catch the `cancel` on a camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, that was a bug, we weren't sending any error on photo cancel for iOS.

I've sent a [PR](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/808) to fix it, should be fine on next release